# Azure: disable .ppk file for ssh connection

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using macos and required to connect to an azure server via ssh. The previous system admin provided me with a .ppk file which he was using to open ssh connection via putty. I want to connect to the server via ssh shell, I believe I need to convert the .ppk file to .pem but the when I run the below command it's prompting me for passphrase which I don't have.

```
puttygen server.ppk -O private-openssh -o server.pem
```

I'm thinking of connecting to the server from a windows pc and disable the .ppk file requirement on the server so that I can connect to the server just with username and password. How can I do that? Or does anybody know other alternative to connect to the server via ssh(creating a new ssh user account in azure portal?)

PS: We will be moving AWS soon so these servers will be decommissioned. Hence I'm not worried about the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your scenario, you could create a new ssh key pair and add id_ras.pub to your VM. Then, you could use the new key to login your VM.

1.Create a new ssh key pair with `ssh-keygen`.

2.Add pub key to your VM, you could do it on Azure Portal.

[image]

Note:It does not overwrite original keys.

3.You could use new private key to login your VM. If you want, you could enable password login. Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Thank you. I found it too confusing to go to 'Reset Password' option to add a new user account :). I love AWS for simplifying(or I think so). Thank you again.